# Netbeans при непонятных условиях не видит некоторые методы std объектов

Tags: c++, netbeans

Вот для примера скриншот, где IDE подчёркивает красным обычный метод `std::string::empty()`:
[image: nb_error]

При этом он предлагает другие методы `std::string`, но того же `size()` тоже нет в списке предлагаемых методов. Компилируется всё нормально, но красные ошибки по коду напрягают. Была также проблема в другом проекте с `std::deque` - IDE вообще не понимала что это, пока не указал в настройках проекта стандарт C++11. В этом проекте стандарт указан, но вот такая беда с `std::string`.

**Это баг, или нужно где-то что-то указать?**

Comment: язык с++ достаточно сложен для парсеров. Вполне возможно, что netbeans не может распарсить заголовки и найти там подходящую функцию.

Comment: А иерархия заголовочных файлов у вас в порядке (в том смысле, что заголовочные файлы, нужные для этого файла включены непосредственно в этот файл, а не косвенно)? Треша с `using namespace std` вне методов нет?

Comment: @VTT, нет, `using` вообще нигде не используется - везде пишу с расширением контекста. Файл "VideoServer.cpp" включает лишь один заголовок "VideoServer.h" , в нём подключается ещё "encryption.h", где и включен `<string>`

Comment: тогда просто добавьте в свой VideoServer.cpp `#include <string>`

Comment: Полностью согласен с обеими комментариями  KoVadim

Comment: @KoVadim, нет, не помогло. Видимо баг...